# getAttribute in a for-loop using querySelector

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement, for-loop

I have this variable

```
var carouselItems = document.querySelectorAll(".carouselItem")
```

that is meant to access this stuff

```
                %div#carouselMain.row
                %div.col-xs-12.col-sm-3.carouselItem{:data => {:image => "images/art0"}}
                    %a{:href => "#"}
                        %div.featured-number
                            01
                        %div.featured-cat
                            Personal Article
                        %h3
                            TITLE
                %div.col-xs-12.col-sm-3.carouselItem{:data => {:image => "images/art1"}}
                    %a{:href => "#"}
                        %div.featured-number
                            02
                        %div.featured-cat
                            Visual Essay
                        %h3
                            TITLE
                %div.col-xs-12.col-sm-3.carouselItem{:data => {:image => "images/art2"}}
                    %a{:href => "#"}
                        %div.featured-number
                            03
                        %div.featured-cat
                            1st Year Feature
                        %h3
                            TITLE
                %div.col-xs-12.col-sm-3.carouselItem{:data => {:image => "images/art3"}}
                    %a{:href => "#"}
                        %div.featured-number
                            04
                        %div.featured-cat
                            Interview
                        %h3
                            TITLE
```

I created a function that has a for loop to access each div & URL for something else, here is the JS code for that:

```
function marqueeGatherData() {
    [].forEach.call(carouselItems, function(index) {
        marqueeVars.totalPanels = index + 1
        for (var j = 0; j < carouselItems.length; j++) {
            if (carouselItems[j].length) {
                var panel_image = this.getAttribute("data-image" + ".png"),
                    panel_caption = this.getElementsByTagName("h3").innerHTML,
                    panel_link = this.getAttribute("href"),
                    panel_category = this.querySelectorAll(".featured-cat").innerHTML,
                    panel_number = this.querySelectorAll(".featured-number").innerHTML
            }
        }
*random stuff*
})
}
```

But the problem arises when you notice that

```
console.log(panel_caption)
```

is returning 4 undefined values, which means the variable is unable to link itself to it's appropriate div. How would I go about solving this problem? I've tried adding the for-loop variable but that didn't do anything. Does it have anything to do with my function being called before the DOM has loaded?

Comment: What is the point of `[].forEach.call(carouselItems, function(index) {` ?

Comment: I was using `getElementsByClassName` before which puts your elements in an array, so I wanted to access it.

Comment: You can't use the lexical `this` this way. Test this example yourself: `[{a:1},{a:2}].forEach(function() { console.log(this.a); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstanding something, why not simply do:

```
function marqueeGatherData() {
    carouselItems.forEach(function(item, index) {
        marqueeVars.totalPanels = index + 1;
        //var panel_image = item.getAttribute("data-image" + ".png"),
        var panel_image = item.dataset.image,
            panel_caption = item.getElementsByTagName("h3").innerHTML,
            panel_link = item.getAttribute("href"),
            panel_category = item.querySelectorAll(".featured-cat").innerHTML,
            panel_number = item.querySelectorAll(".featured-number").innerHTML;

        // random stuff
    });
}
```

The second argument of [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Syntax) is the `index`.

**Side-remark:** 
`item.getAttribute("data-image.png")` doesn't look right as attributes cannot contain periods. If you want to access the data attribute's value of e.g. `data-image`, use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property e.g. `item.dataset.image`.